# ERROR Couldn't fetch mysqli and mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysqli

ME DA ESTE ERROR:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:---  on line 67 
>   Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:---  on line 69

```
        <?php

if (isset($_GET['cat']))    {
        //Seleccionamos lo filtrado por el numero de categoria:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM detall_productes WHERE codi_categoria =".$_GET['cat'];
}else{
        //Seleccionamos todo de nuestra BD
$sql = "SELECT * FROM detall_productes";
}

    //Realizamos la consulta gracias a la sentencia SQL
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        //relacionamos HTML con BD

//<TD> FILA DE DATO
echo '<tr> 
                            <td class="align-middle"><img src="images/productes/'.$row['imatge'].'" class="img-thumbnail mr-2" style="height: 50px;" />'.utf8_encode($row['nom']).'</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">'.utf8_encode($row['nom_categoria']).'</td>
                            <td class="align-middle text-right">'.$row['preu'].' €</td>
                                <td class="align-middle">

                                <form class="form-inline" action="carrito.php" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="codi" value="'.$row['codi'].'" />
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-2" name="quantitat" min="1" value="1" style="width: 50px;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></button>
                                </form>
                            </td> 
                        </tr>';

}   
?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El error indica que esta llamada: `$result = $conn->query($sql);` no está devolviendo un conjunto de resultados, sino `NULL`, sea porque `$conn` es nula, sea porque la consulta tiene algún error.

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP, tu código es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público.

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que esta llamada: `$result = $conn->query($sql);` no está devolviendo un conjunto de resultados, sino NULL, sea porque `$conn` es nula, sea porque la consulta tiene algún error.

Conviene que evalúes el estado de las variables que intervienen en el código, y que escribas un código controlado que informe de la situación.

Prueba a hacerlo de esta manera. En el código que sigue también he aplicado una recomendación del Manual de PHP que dice que no conviene mezclar estilos en mysqli, tú tenías una mezcla entre el estilo procedural y el estilo orientado a objetos. He aplicado este último estilo en todo, el código es más legible y más *moderno* de ese modo.

Espero te sirva.

```
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    //Seleccionamos lo filtrado por el numero de categoria:
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM detall_productes WHERE codi_categoria =".$_GET['cat'];
}else{
    //Seleccionamos todo de nuestra BD
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM detall_productes";
}

if ($conn){
    //Realizamos la consulta gracias a la sentencia SQL
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

        /* obtener un array asociativo */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            /*
            *Aquí
            *toda la parte
            *HTML
            *de tu código
        */


        }//Esta llave cierra el while

        /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
        $result->free();
    }else{

        echo "Error en la consulta: ".$conn->error;
    }

}else{

    echo "La conexión es nula, revise sus credenciales de conexión";

}
```